# a inequality similar to geometric means

Tags: calculus, algebra-precalculus, inequality

Let $a$, $b$ be two positive constants. We sure have
$$
a^2+b^2\geq 2ab
$$
My question: would it be possible to have an inequality like
$$
a^2+b^2\geq Ca^{2+\epsilon}b^{1-\eta}
$$
where $C$, $\epsilon$ and $\eta$ are some positive constant?

Thank you!

Comment: nvm.... I think it is impossible. Just divide both side by $a^{2+\epsilon}$ and increasing $a$ we would have a contradiction...

Comment: Why did you lose $2$? It doesn't make sense to compare with to geometric mean without $2$

Comment: @You'reInMyEye I am ok with any constant...

Comment: $a^{1+\epsilon}$ will make more sense.

Comment: $C a^{2+\varepsilon} b^{1-\eta}$ is way bigger than $a^2+b^2$ for any $a$ big enough, so: no.

Comment: @JackD'Aurizio I agree. this is what I said in the first comment... Thank you anyway

Comment: Yes. Replacing it by $a^{1+\epsilon}$ gives some useful information. See my answer below.

Answer (score 1):

The following inequality is the key toward the proof of Holder's inequality:

For $u, v\geq 0$, and $p, q>0$ with $\frac1p + \frac 1q =1$,

$$
uv\leq \frac {u^p}p+ \frac{v^q}q.
$$

Substitute $$a^2 = \frac{u^p}p, \ \ \mathrm{and} \ \   b^2=\frac {v^q}q.$$